# ASP.NET Send Cookies to client Browser

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, cookies, httpcontext

I'm integrating a single sign on over 2 ASP.Net applications. For that matter i have a web service that is called by the main app. when a user logs in. this web service authenticates the user in my second application and brings back the authentication cookies i need to deliver to the client browser so he can navigate freely and logged in both applications.

I was planning to use ***HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie)*** in order to deliver the new cookies but this seems not to work as no cookies are added what so ever...

Any ideas on what might be going wrong?

here is my code:

```
var service = new localhost.UserManagement();
service.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
if (service.AuthenticateUser("test@user.pt", "test"))
{ 
    var collection = service.CookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri("http://localhost"));
    foreach (Cookie item in collection)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(CookieConverter(item));
    }
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    return true;
}

return false;
```

Note: ***CookieConverter(item)*** is used to convert Cookie object i receive to HttpCookie

Thanks

```
private HttpCookie CookieConverter(Cookie cookie)
        {
            var result = new HttpCookie(cookie.Name);

            result.Value = cookie.Value;
            result.Domain = cookie.Domain;
            result.Expires = cookie.Expires;
            result.Path = cookie.Path;
            result.Secure = cookie.Secure;
            result.HttpOnly = cookie.HttpOnly;

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: FYI, "ASP.NET" is one word - no spaces

Comment: can you put the code in that method?

Comment: var result = new HttpCookie(cookie.Name);

result.Value = cookie.Value;
result.Domain = cookie.Domain;
result.Expires = cookie.Expires;
result.Path = cookie.Path;
result.Secure = cookie.Secure;
result.HttpOnly = cookie.HttpOnly;

return result;

Answer (score 0):

You should check:

- collection is empty? Could you set braeakpoint and check collection?
- where is this code located? (.aspx page, web service, http handler?)
- try to create minimalistic "Cookie setter" that just add simple cookie in any way

Comment: Code works fine, did run every step in debug and all the cookies are received, converted and added to Response correctly.

Code is located in a separate Class Library that handles all the web services i need to use. It's called from asp control upon a button click (not that simple but basically this is what happens (main app. is a Sitefinity app. so its a widget that trigers this)

Will try to create a minimalistic setter, gimme 5min will tell you how it went

Comment: ok, minimalistic "cookie setter" worked, i could deliver the test cookie, so what might cause other cookies not to be delivered?

Comment: If minimalistic setter works, you should try to step by step changing it to you code, and you can find out what change is critical